# How can I initialize a pair of byteArray inside a constructor in koltin?

Tags: arrays, kotlin

How do I initialize the pair of ByteArray in the secondary constructor? Or is it even possible to do so?

```
class Example (val id:String,
                  val text:String,
                  val fromId:String,
                  val toId:String,
                  val timestamp: Long,
                  val pair: Pair<ByteArray, ByteArray>) {

    constructor() : this("", "", "", "", -1,  )
}
```

Comment: What do you want to initialise it to? What bytes should the pair of byte arrays contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's easy enough to create and initialise a `ByteArray` within your secondary constructor.

However, that's not all you need: the parameter is a `Pair<ByteArray, ByteArray>`, a pair of byte arrays.

It looks like you want the simplest possible, ‘empty’ object.  If the pair were nullable, then a single null would probably be simplest; or if the byte arrays it contained were nullable, then you could have a pair of nulls.  But neither are the case, so the next-simplest thing would be a pair of *empty* byte arrays.

You could create those with the [`byteArrayOf()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/byte-array-of.html) function, and the [`to`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/to.html) function to combine them into a pair:

```
    byteArrayOf() to byteArrayOf()
```

The same method would work if you need non-empty arrays, too:

```
    byteArrayOf(1, 2) to byteArrayOf(3, 4)
```

(That would even work with non-constant values.)

Alternatively, there are ways to convert another structure into a byte array, e.g.:

```
    someString.split(",").map{ it.toByte() }.toByteArray()
```

Or to create one algorithmically, e.g.:

```
    ByteArray(10){ (it * 2).toByte() }
```

Comment: Thanks your answer helped but I would also like to know if I had to initialize the byte array then how can I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  The examples I gave all create initialised byte arrays.

Comment: oh what I mean is this was for a pair of byteArray but what if it was only byteArray, For example : if one of the parameters were val first : ByteArray then how do I initialize it inside the secondary constructor?

Comment: Exactly as shown above. For example: `class C(val first: ByteArray) { constructor() : this(byteArrayOf(1, 2, 3)) }`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. Note that both arrays will be the size of 0

```
constructor() : this("", "", "", "", -1,  ByteArray(0) to ByteArray(0))
```